# Youtube Command Prompt

Tags: command-line, youtube-dl

I tried to download a youtube video with the following command:

```
C:\Users\[me\OneDrive\Desktop\Test>youtube-dl -fURL
```

I've also tried:

```
C:\Users\[me\OneDrive\Desktop\Test>youtube-dl -f[URL]
```

but I keep getting error messages such as:

```
'youtube-dl' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

And

```
youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL
```

can someone help and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add the path of the Youtube-dl executable to your Path variable OR navigate to that folder and run the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
cd /[drive] [path]
```

The path must be location of youtube-dl ...
then

```
youtube-dl.exe -some-command "[url]"
```

type the url must be inside this ""